# How to prevent internet access in Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

How do I setup my Docker networks to allow only internal and host access?

I have been using a user-defined network to prevent my containers from accessing the internet.

```
networks:
  no-internet:
    internal: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.19.0.0/16
```

This works great. However, I would like to allow my containers to connect to the host so that I can use XDebug. If I use the default Docker network, I can setup Xdebug to connect to the host via `host.docker.internal`. Once I add the containers to the `no-internet` user-defined network, the containers lose access to the host.

[image: Internal + Host]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting `internal`, when creating your user defined networks, set `com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=false`. That would prevent NAT masquerading outbound traffic from that particular network (which is how Docker connects containers to the host network when using IPv4).

The following is how you'd do it with the docker-cli.

```
docker network create --subnet 172.19.0.0/16 \
   -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=false \
   -o com.docker.network.bridge.name=nointernet \
   nointernet
```

And this is what it would look like in with Docker Compose

```
networks:
   front:
     driver: bridge
     driver_opts:
       com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade: 'false'
     ipam:
       driver: default
       config:
       - subnet: 172.19.0.0/16
```

Comment: Thanks! Docker for Mac has a web server running. If I run `curl 127.0.0.1:8081` from the host env (macOS) I get a response from the server. If I run `curl host.docker.internal:8081` from within a container, it doesn't resolve.

Comment: Docker for mac is a bit tricky. You can go directly to the container in Linux. Within docker, the containers can communicate with each other by container name, so long as they're on the same network (you can have multiple networks per container). On Mac, if you need to connect to a container directly without sharing the host port, you need to create a VPN endpoint within your Docker network. There are a number of tools/tutorials out there to help you do that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what XDebug is, so I might be totally wrong; but my intuition is that this is an easy case.

Put Xdebug in a container on the `no-internet` network.

Comment: It's just a debug tool that runs connects a debugger to PHP. It's already running in the Apache container which is in the `no-internet` network. My host needs to connect to the container and cannot.