# Remove internet access to a docker container, but should be able to connect to a remote SFTP server via SSH

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

As mentioned in the subject, I want to create a docker container where it has no internet connection, but it can connect to a remote SFTP server, via SSH protocol. Picture below is **WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**:
[image]
What I was able to do so far is to remove the internet connection by specifying `internal: true` in the docker-compose file:

```
networks:
  backend:
    name: true
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
```

But with this network setting, the docker container cannot connect to the SFTP server.
So with this, I tried using `enable_ip_masquerade` to `false` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544970/how-to-prevent-internet-access-in-docker-containers).

```
networks:
  backend:
    name: backend
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade: "false"
```

But still, the docker container cannot connect to the SFTP server.

Greatly appreciate any ideas/inputs on how to do this correctly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, just removing the `ports` mapping in docker-compose, and leaving the `expose` did the trick.